# Adding integers split into vectors

Tags: c++, stl

So, i'm trying to build a program that takes 2 integers. Later it splits the plus/minus sign and the digits and saves them into vectors. Last i would like to add those two integers. I managed to split the ints into the vectors and vector.size() gives me correct answers although i can't print them. Any clue on how to make the addition of the integers?
Thanks,

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int
main(){
cout<<"Give 2 integers.\n";
int a,b;
cin>>a;
cin>>b;

vector<int> adigits;
//10 for positive, 20 for negative integer
adigits.push_back(a<0 ? 20:10);
  a=abs(a);
  while(a>0){
  adigits.push_back(a%10);
  a=a/10;
 }

  vector<int> bdigits;
  //10 for positive, 20 for negative integer
  bdigits.push_back(b<0 ? 20:10);
  b=abs(b);
  while(b>0){
    bdigits.push_back(b%10);
    b=b/10;
  }

 vector <int>::size_type c;
 vector <int>::size_type d;
 c=adigits.size();
 d=bdigits.size();

  cout<<c;
  cout<<d;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: *my code can't handle it.* What is the behavior it shows? What is the behavior it is supposed to show? There are only *C++ programmers* here no *mind readers*.

Comment: I could swear this exact same question was asked just over an hour ago, but now I can't find the other question...

Comment: My code now behaves normally. A problem i seem to have is that the terminal closes without printing the vector sizes, why is that?

Comment: @user1179375: What does *normally* mean? You have to understand that people reading the Question do not know what you are trying to do.You have to ask the Question in a manner that they understand what you are trying to do, only then can they help.To get a good answer you need to frame a good question, which expresses: what you want to achieve, How you are trying to achieve it, What is the problem that you are facing.

Comment: ok, i made all the neccessary edits in my opinion. new to this site, still trying to learn the habits.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
adigits.push_back(a<0 ? 20:10);
 while(a>0){
  adigits.push_back(a%10);
  a=a/10;
 }
```

This will just push a `20` onto `adigits` if `a` is already less than zero before the loop executes even once.

Rethink your logic; the `bdigits` loop has the same flaw.

Comment: I see now. All i have to do is to change my loop condition to
abs(a)>0. Right?

Comment: @user1179375 So long as you know how the modulus operator (`%`) behaves with negative numbers :-).

Comment: changed to abs(a and b) before the loop just to be sure. :P